# Two div classes side-by-side

Tags: html, css

Even though I used float, my two div classes do not want to align side-by-side. How to do it?
Basically the entire width is 520px and each box is 250px in width with a margin between the boxes of 20px.

```
<div id="car-box">
<div class="well-car">
                <div class="add_box">
                    <h1 class="add_heading">car model</h1>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="car-brand">
                    <a class="button" href="www.placehold.it">car brand</a>
                </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.car-box {
    width:520px;
    height:500px;
    border:5px dashed blue;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left
}

.well-car {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:10px solid red;
}
.car-brand {
    width: 250px;
    height:250px;
    border:10px dashed blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    float:left
}
```

Here Fiddle...[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/b3kd9mwf/24/)

Comment: Everyone seems to be missing that it should be `#car-box` instead of `.car-box` or `class="car-box"` instead of `id` - the way you have it you're not styling the outer div at all so it's *not* 520px wide (but that's not the only issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your border width gets added to the content widths. `250+2*10 + 250+2*10 == 540`.

(You can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing how do browsers calculate block elements' sizes)

**For your custom styles it's usually best to set `box-sizing: border-box`**(http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Edit: and yes, also `float:left` on the `.well-car` class, as others pointed out.

Comment: Yes, but `250+2*5 + 250+2*10 == 530`

Comment: Oh, whoops, I forgot the border is on both sides. By the way, the calculation would be `250+2*10 + 250+2*10 == 540`. However, updating it still doesn't fix the problem for a few reasons.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was glanced at wrong margins ;) And you're right, there are more problems with it.

Comment: lol, this starts to look like some sort "spot the difference" game :D

Comment: Almost there, just 250+2*10 + 250+2*10 == 5**4**0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to float `.well-car` as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/b3kd9mwf/26/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **float: left;** to your div with the class "well-car".

```
.well-car {
width:250px;
height:250px;
border:10px solid red;
float: left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not floating your elements correctly. Class `wellcar` should be floated to the `left` and class `car-brand` should be floated to the `right`. The following code should work.

```
#car-box {
    width:520px;
    height:500px;
    border:5px dashed blue;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.well-car {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:10px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.car-brand {
    width: 250px;
    height:250px;
    border:10px dashed blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    float:right;
}
```